Could a tankless water heater work to heat up tub and kitchen sink with gas shut off?
I’m looking for a way to heat up our water at least to our tub and kitchen sink. The small electric heater thing that you plug in and place in the water seems too dangerous!
I saw a reasonably priced tankless water heater but I don't know if it’s an addition to a tanked water heater or if I could use it for my situation.

From some of the edited-out information, here is something you could try instead of your posted idea: contact your gas company to work out a payment solution, or the government for assistance. If the trend in the area you live in is to support seniors and others who have fallen on hard times, winter heat assistance should be available.

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments aren't an appropriate way to respond to answers.

There are a number of different ways to permanently install a water heater:

Traditional tank - resistance electric or natural gas - This is a tank, typically between 30 and 50 gallons for an entire house, though smaller and larger tanks are available. (Well, larger are somewhat limited now for residential installation due to regulations designed to promote installation of more efficient water heaters, but I digress.) This requires a plumber or serious DIY skills to install - plumbing, gas (if gas powered) and electric (if electricity powered). This is typically enough to supply a household for all common needs - washing dishes, bathing, etc. with capacity for all except for the most extreme (teenagers taking extra long showers...) situations.

Heat Pump Tank - this uses electricity to heat a tank of water more efficiently than a traditional resistance water heater, but may take longer to do so, costs more (because more complex) and has the same installation requirements except possibly a smaller electric circuit (but still dedicated circuit, so still some real work involved).

Point-of-use tank - This can vary from a very small tank ("instant hot") to a 6 gallon or possibly larger tank installed to serve a single kitchen  or bathroom. It is fundamentally no different from a traditional tank except for size, and requires similar skills to install. However, because it is smaller and near the point of use, it provides hot water faster than a traditional tank and can often be installed in locations such as under a kitchen sink where there is no room for a traditional tank.

Tankless large water heater - This is installed like a traditional tank but does not store any water. That has some advantages - in theory lower energy usage because water is not heated and then cooling down while waiting to be used - and some disadvantages - very high gas or electric requirement. For electric this is a big concern as a tankless water heater can easily use as much power as everything else in the house (oven, HVAC, lighting, etc.) put together. Installation skills are similar to tank water heaters.

Tankless small water heater - This is similar to a point-of-use small tank, but tankless. It requires the same skills to install but has the advantage of faster hot water because it does not have to travel through the house.


But for temporary, plug-in, water heating, your options are:

Small appliances - This is the only option that doesn't require plumbing and electrical or gas skills to install. These include:

Immersion heaters - As noted, these pose a serious risk of burns.
Electric kettles - Designed to heat up a small quantity of water very quickly for making hot beverages.
Electric coffee urns/hot water pots - Designed to heat up a larger quantity of water (typically between 1/2 gallon and 2 gallons), generally a bit slower than an electric kettle but designed to keep warm for extended time.
A pot of water on the stove - gas or electric. This is what they did in the old days, and can still work when needed.



Keep in mind that any electric plug-in appliances (as opposed to a hardwired electric water heater, tank or tankless) is generally limited to the size of a "standard" receptacle circuit. In the US that means a maximum of 20A @ 120V = 2,400 Watts, but for reasons normally limited to 15A = 1,800 Watts. Which heats a lot of water very slowly or a little water fairly quickly. For comparison, a typical electric tank water heater is rated at 4,500 Watts.

A tankless water heater would probably serve your needs well. A portable unit wouldn't require installation. You'd simply connect a hose to a water source, plug it in, and station the unit near the need for hot water.
Note that these units consume a fair bit of energy, so cost savings may not be what you hope. Gas is probably cheaper if that's yet an option.

If you must go electric, heat - pump units can rival gas for efficiency, sometimes even beat It. Of course they are more expensive.

Is there such a thing as a portable air pump water heater?

In theory possible;. Take a sufficiently powerful refrigerator or air conditioner mechanism and strap cooling jackets to the hot side, the motor, and the water pump.  You would get both the pump's output and (most of) the electrical energy turned into heat by the pumps. I do not have a good handle on how large this would have to be to heat water effectively given its density. Add all the usual precautions for portable electric devices around water, of course.
